# Connection issues with Cosmos DB SDK

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Im trying to connect to a CosmosDB instance using the Java SDK. My code to do so looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String host = "https://mycosmosinstance.cosmos.azure.com:443";
  String key = "mykey";

  InetSocketAddress proxy = InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("corporate.proxy.net", 8080);

  ConnectionPolicy.getDefaultPolicy().setProxy(new ProxyOptions(ProxyOptions.Type.HTTP, proxy));

  CosmosClient cc = new CosmosClientBuilder()
                     .endpoint(host)
                     .key(key)
                     .gatewayMode()
                     .buildClient();   
  cc.getDatabase("MY_DB");

  cc.close();
}
```

As the example shows Im behind a corporate proxy. Connection should not be an issue though, because our mongo clients work fine. Ports are open as I can telnet directly. I have no access to the Azure control plane.

Im getting RuntimeExceptions that says "Client initialization failed. Check if the endpoint is reachable and if your auth token is valid". The token is the same used for our mongodb clients.

Trying to connect to 443 and the 10255 (being the mongo port) yields a 404 and a timeout.

Is the code wrong? Anyone have experience with this?

```
Timeout log:


WARNING: [id:a0bf804d-1, L:/10.0.2.15:44498 - R:mycosmosinstance.cosmos.azure.com/10.x.x.x:10255] The connection observed an error

io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException

 

Sep 10, 2021 10:03:28 AM com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxGatewayStoreModel lambda$toDocumentServiceResponse$3

SEVERE: Network failure

io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException

 

Sep 10, 2021 10:03:28 AM com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl lambda$getDatabaseAccountFromEndpoint$142

WARNING: Failed to retrieve database account information. io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException

Sep 10, 2021 10:03:28 AM com.azure.cosmos.implementation.GlobalEndpointManager lambda$getDatabaseAccountFromAnyLocationsAsync$2

SEVERE: Fail to reach global gateway [http://mycosmosinstance.cosmos.azure.com:10255], [{"innerErrorMessage":null,"cosmosDiagnostics":{"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","requestLatencyInMs":60636,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.031464262Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:03:28.667618587Z","responseStatisticsList":[],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":[],"retryContext":{"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryLatency":0,"retryCount":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":null},"gatewayStatistics":{"sessionToken":null,"operationType":"Read","resourceType":"DatabaseAccount","statusCode":0,"subStatusCode":10002,"requestCharge":null,"requestTimeline":[{"eventName":"connectionCreated","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.033787036Z","durationInMicroSec":567084},{"eventName":"connectionConfigured","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.600871087Z","durationInMicroSec":10852},{"eventName":"requestSent","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.611723553Z","durationInMicroSec":12087},{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.623811005Z","durationInMicroSec":60036821},{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":null,"durationInMicroSec":0}],"partitionKeyRangeId":null},"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"26202 KB","availableMemory":"6023590 KB","systemCpuLoad":"(2021-09-10T08:03:02.912144761Z 3.5%), (2021-09-10T08:03:07.912029515Z 3.2%), (2021-09-10T08:03:12.911460277Z 3.1%), (2021-09-10T08:03:17.911173112Z 3.5%), (2021-09-10T08:03:22.912067928Z 2.2%), (2021-09-10T08:03:27.911201387Z 2.4%)","availableProcessors":4},"clientCfgs":{"id":0,"connectionMode":"GATEWAY","numberOfClients":1,"connCfg":{"rntbd":null,"gw":"(cps:1000, rto:PT5S, icto:PT1M, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [])"}}}]

Sep 10, 2021 10:03:28 AM com.azure.cosmos.implementation.GlobalEndpointManager lambda$startRefreshLocationTimerAsync$12

SEVERE: startRefreshLocationTimerAsync() - Unable to refresh database account from any location. Exception: {"ClassName":"CosmosException","userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","statusCode":0,"resourceAddress":"https://mycosmosinstance.cosmos.azure.com:10255/","innerErrorMessage":null,"causeInfo":"[class: class io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException, message: null]","responseHeaders":"{x-ms-substatus=10002}","requestHeaders":"[Accept=application/json, x-ms-date=Fri, 10 Sep 2021 08:02:27 GMT]","cosmosDiagnostics":{"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","requestLatencyInMs":60636,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.031464262Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:03:28.667618587Z","responseStatisticsList":[],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":[],"retryContext":{"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryLatency":0,"retryCount":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":null},"gatewayStatistics":{"sessionToken":null,"operationType":"Read","resourceType":"DatabaseAccount","statusCode":0,"subStatusCode":10002,"requestCharge":null,"requestTimeline":[{"eventName":"connectionCreated","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.033787036Z","durationInMicroSec":567084},{"eventName":"connectionConfigured","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.600871087Z","durationInMicroSec":10852},{"eventName":"requestSent","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.611723553Z","durationInMicroSec":12087},{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.623811005Z","durationInMicroSec":60036821},{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":null,"durationInMicroSec":0}],"partitionKeyRangeId":null},"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"26202 KB","availableMemory":"6023590 KB","systemCpuLoad":"(2021-09-10T08:03:02.912144761Z 3.5%), (2021-09-10T08:03:07.912029515Z 3.2%), (2021-09-10T08:03:12.911460277Z 3.1%), (2021-09-10T08:03:17.911173112Z 3.5%), (2021-09-10T08:03:22.912067928Z 2.2%), (2021-09-10T08:03:27.911201387Z 2.4%)","availableProcessors":4},"clientCfgs":{"id":0,"connectionMode":"GATEWAY","numberOfClients":1,"connCfg":{"rntbd":null,"gw":"(cps:1000, rto:PT5S, icto:PT1M, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [])"}}}

{"ClassName":"CosmosException","userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","statusCode":0,"resourceAddress":"https://mycosmosinstance.cosmos.azure.com:10255/","innerErrorMessage":null,"causeInfo":"[class: class io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException, message: null]","responseHeaders":"{x-ms-substatus=10002}","requestHeaders":"[Accept=application/json, x-ms-date=Fri, 10 Sep 2021 08:02:27 GMT]","cosmosDiagnostics":{"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","requestLatencyInMs":60636,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.031464262Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:03:28.667618587Z","responseStatisticsList":[],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":[],"retryContext":{"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryLatency":0,"retryCount":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":null},"gatewayStatistics":{"sessionToken":null,"operationType":"Read","resourceType":"DatabaseAccount","statusCode":0,"subStatusCode":10002,"requestCharge":null,"requestTimeline":[{"eventName":"connectionCreated","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.033787036Z","durationInMicroSec":567084},{"eventName":"connectionConfigured","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.600871087Z","durationInMicroSec":10852},{"eventName":"requestSent","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.611723553Z","durationInMicroSec":12087},{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:02:28.623811005Z","durationInMicroSec":60036821},{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":null,"durationInMicroSec":0}],"partitionKeyRangeId":null},"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"26202 KB","availableMemory":"6023590 KB","systemCpuLoad":"(2021-09-10T08:03:02.912144761Z 3.5%), (2021-09-10T08:03:07.912029515Z 3.2%), (2021-09-10T08:03:12.911460277Z 3.1%), (2021-09-10T08:03:17.911173112Z 3.5%), (2021-09-10T08:03:22.912067928Z 2.2%), (2021-09-10T08:03:27.911201387Z 2.4%)","availableProcessors":4},"clientCfgs":{"id":0,"connectionMode":"GATEWAY","numberOfClients":1,"connCfg":{"rntbd":null,"gw":"(cps:1000, rto:PT5S, icto:PT1M, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [])"}}}

                at com.azure.cosmos.BridgeInternal.createCosmosException(BridgeInternal.java:466)


404 log:

ep 10, 2021 10:18:29 AM com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl$1 getDatabaseAccountFromEndpoint

INFO: Getting database account endpoint from https://mycosmosinstance.cosmos.azure.com:443

Sep 10, 2021 10:18:30 AM com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl lambda$getDatabaseAccountFromEndpoint$142

WARNING: Failed to retrieve database account information. {"ClassName":"CosmosException","userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","statusCode":404,"resourceAddress":"https://mycosmosinstance.cosmos.azure.com:443/","error":"{\"code\":\"NotFound\",\"message\":\"null, StatusCode: NotFound\",\"additionalErrorInfo\":null}","innerErrorMessage":"null, StatusCode: NotFound","causeInfo":null,"responseHeaders":"{content-length=0, Date=Fri, 10 Sep 2021 08:18:30 GMT}","requestHeaders":"[Accept=application/json, x-ms-date=Fri, 10 Sep 2021 08:18:29 GMT]","cosmosDiagnostics":{"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","requestLatencyInMs":744,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:29.891310289Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.635990134Z","responseStatisticsList":[],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":[],"retryContext":{"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryLatency":0,"retryCount":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":null},"gatewayStatistics":{"sessionToken":null,"operationType":"Read","resourceType":"DatabaseAccount","statusCode":404,"subStatusCode":0,"requestCharge":null,"requestTimeline":[{"eventName":"connectionCreated","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:29.894688313Z","durationInMicroSec":637342},{"eventName":"connectionConfigured","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.532031288Z","durationInMicroSec":12332},{"eventName":"requestSent","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.544363773Z","durationInMicroSec":9266},{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.553630445Z","durationInMicroSec":63763},{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.617394320Z","durationInMicroSec":11039}],"partitionKeyRangeId":null},"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"25671 KB","availableMemory":"6024121 KB","systemCpuLoad":"empty","availableProcessors":4},"clientCfgs":{"id":0,"connectionMode":"GATEWAY","numberOfClients":1,"connCfg":{"rntbd":null,"gw":"(cps:1000, rto:PT5S, icto:PT1M, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [])"}}}

Sep 10, 2021 10:18:30 AM com.azure.cosmos.implementation.GlobalEndpointManager lambda$getDatabaseAccountFromAnyLocationsAsync$2

SEVERE: Fail to reach global gateway [https://mycosmosinstance.cosmos.azure.com:443], [{"innerErrorMessage":"null, StatusCode: NotFound","cosmosDiagnostics":{"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","requestLatencyInMs":744,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:29.891310289Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.635990134Z","responseStatisticsList":[],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":[],"retryContext":{"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryLatency":0,"retryCount":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":null},"gatewayStatistics":{"sessionToken":null,"operationType":"Read","resourceType":"DatabaseAccount","statusCode":404,"subStatusCode":0,"requestCharge":null,"requestTimeline":[{"eventName":"connectionCreated","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:29.894688313Z","durationInMicroSec":637342},{"eventName":"connectionConfigured","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.532031288Z","durationInMicroSec":12332},{"eventName":"requestSent","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.544363773Z","durationInMicroSec":9266},{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.553630445Z","durationInMicroSec":63763},{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.617394320Z","durationInMicroSec":11039}],"partitionKeyRangeId":null},"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"25671 KB","availableMemory":"6024121 KB","systemCpuLoad":"empty","availableProcessors":4},"clientCfgs":{"id":0,"connectionMode":"GATEWAY","numberOfClients":1,"connCfg":{"rntbd":null,"gw":"(cps:1000, rto:PT5S, icto:PT1M, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [])"}}}]

Sep 10, 2021 10:18:30 AM com.azure.cosmos.implementation.GlobalEndpointManager lambda$startRefreshLocationTimerAsync$12

SEVERE: startRefreshLocationTimerAsync() - Unable to refresh database account from any location. Exception: {"ClassName":"CosmosException","userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","statusCode":404,"resourceAddress":"https://mycosmosinstance.cosmos.azure.com:443/","error":"{\"code\":\"NotFound\",\"message\":\"null, StatusCode: NotFound\",\"additionalErrorInfo\":null}","innerErrorMessage":"null, StatusCode: NotFound","causeInfo":null,"responseHeaders":"{content-length=0, Date=Fri, 10 Sep 2021 08:18:30 GMT}","requestHeaders":"[Accept=application/json, x-ms-date=Fri, 10 Sep 2021 08:18:29 GMT]","cosmosDiagnostics":{"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","requestLatencyInMs":744,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:29.891310289Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.635990134Z","responseStatisticsList":[],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":[],"retryContext":{"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryLatency":0,"retryCount":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":null},"gatewayStatistics":{"sessionToken":null,"operationType":"Read","resourceType":"DatabaseAccount","statusCode":404,"subStatusCode":0,"requestCharge":null,"requestTimeline":[{"eventName":"connectionCreated","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:29.894688313Z","durationInMicroSec":637342},{"eventName":"connectionConfigured","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.532031288Z","durationInMicroSec":12332},{"eventName":"requestSent","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.544363773Z","durationInMicroSec":9266},{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.553630445Z","durationInMicroSec":63763},{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.617394320Z","durationInMicroSec":11039}],"partitionKeyRangeId":null},"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"25671 KB","availableMemory":"6024121 KB","systemCpuLoad":"empty","availableProcessors":4},"clientCfgs":{"id":0,"connectionMode":"GATEWAY","numberOfClients":1,"connCfg":{"rntbd":null,"gw":"(cps:1000, rto:PT5S, icto:PT1M, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [])"}}}

{"ClassName":"CosmosException","userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","statusCode":404,"resourceAddress":"https://mycosmosinstance.cosmos.azure.com:443/","error":"{\"code\":\"NotFound\",\"message\":\"null, StatusCode: NotFound\",\"additionalErrorInfo\":null}","innerErrorMessage":"null, StatusCode: NotFound","causeInfo":null,"responseHeaders":"{content-length=0, Date=Fri, 10 Sep 2021 08:18:30 GMT}","requestHeaders":"[Accept=application/json, x-ms-date=Fri, 10 Sep 2021 08:18:29 GMT]","cosmosDiagnostics":{"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.18.0 Linux/5.4.0-71-generic JRE/16","requestLatencyInMs":744,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:29.891310289Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.635990134Z","responseStatisticsList":[],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":[],"retryContext":{"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryLatency":0,"retryCount":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":null},"gatewayStatistics":{"sessionToken":null,"operationType":"Read","resourceType":"DatabaseAccount","statusCode":404,"subStatusCode":0,"requestCharge":null,"requestTimeline":[{"eventName":"connectionCreated","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:29.894688313Z","durationInMicroSec":637342},{"eventName":"connectionConfigured","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.532031288Z","durationInMicroSec":12332},{"eventName":"requestSent","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.544363773Z","durationInMicroSec":9266},{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.553630445Z","durationInMicroSec":63763},{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":"2021-09-10T08:18:30.617394320Z","durationInMicroSec":11039}],"partitionKeyRangeId":null},"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"25671 KB","availableMemory":"6024121 KB","systemCpuLoad":"empty","availableProcessors":4},"clientCfgs":{"id":0,"connectionMode":"GATEWAY","numberOfClients":1,"connCfg":{"rntbd":null,"gw":"(cps:1000, rto:PT5S, icto:PT1M, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [])"}}}

                at com.azure.cosmos.BridgeInternal.createCosmosException(BridgeInternal.java:475)
```

Comment: The SDK you are using is for a SQL API account and you mention Mongo, is this a Mongo or a SQL API account you are connecting to?

Comment: Im trying to use the change feed. I guess that means mongo, but im kind of shotgun debugging right now.

Comment: Change Feed is a feature that is present in multiple types of Cosmos DB accounts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed). The problem you are facing is that the Account type you have (Mongo) should be using Mongo drivers. The SDK you are using is for a SQL API account type. For Mongo accounts, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#change-feed-in-apis-for-cassandra-and-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

If you use an HTTP proxy, make sure it can support the number of connections configured in the SDK GatewayConnectionConfig. Otherwise, you'll face connection issues. And to use any proxy configuration, Java requires you to set the system environment property java.net.useSystemProxies to true.

Also, if the proxy you're using require authentication! This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/proxying) goes over adding authentication information to the proxy which should help alleviate the 403 responses. If so, you eventually can get into a state where no Netty IO thread can lead to a ReadTimeoutException failure.

Due to Invalid coding pattern: Blocking Netty IO thread, might result in low throughput, high latency, and io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException failures. The workaround is to switch the thread when you know the operation takes time.

Use `.preferredRegions(Collections.singletonList("West US"))` where West US is just an example. Set preferred location to the Cosmos DB region closest to the application.

Checkout: [Diagnose and troubleshoot Azure Cosmos DB Java v4 SDK request timeout exceptions](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-request-timeout-java-sdk-v4-sql.md#diagnose-and-troubleshoot-azure-cosmos-db-java-v4-sdk-request-timeout-exceptions) and for status code 404: [Diagnose and troubleshoot Azure Cosmos DB not found exceptions](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-not-found.md#diagnose-and-troubleshoot-azure-cosmos-db-not-found-exceptions)